# Regex to Extract #hashtags from MMD metadata in Python

Tags: python, regex, multimarkdown

I'm trying to extract all the #hashtags from the "Tags: #tag1 #tag2" line of a multimarkdown plaintext file. (I'm in Python multiline mode.)

I've tried using lookaheads:

```
^(?=Tags:\s.*)#(\w+)\b
```

and lookbehinds:

```
#(\w+)\b(?<=Tags:^\s)
```

Plain vanilla `#(\w+)\b` works, except it picks up any #hashtag that might appear later in the document.

Any hints, help, instruction appreciated.

Comment: Try use dotall to force dot to match line breaks

Comment: Something you might give a thought: extract all lines that contain "Tags:" followed by at least one tag, then from all the extracted lines, extract the tags. Otherwise, I know that the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) in python 3.X supports search anchor `\G` and if you are using this module, then you can use [this regex](http://regex101.com/r/dI6zS8) in your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = "\n\n#bogus\nTags: #foo #bar\n"
```

First, you need to get the line:

```
line = re.findall(r'Tags:.+\n', text)
# line = ['Tags: #foo #bar\n']
```

Lastly, you need to get the tags from the line:

```
tags = re.findall(r'#(\w+)', line[0])
# tags = ['foo', 'bar']
tags = re.findall(r'#\w+', line[0])
# tags = ['#foo', '#bar']
```

Lookbehind won't work since you would need to provide a pattern that doesn't have a fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

First get index where hash is located in the input text and then use [re.findall](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to get repeated captures. Following example prints `['#tag1', '#tag2']`

```
text = "Tags: #tag1 #tag2"

matched = re.search(r'^Tags([^#]+)', text)
if matched:
    tag_text = text[matched.end():]
    hash_tags = re.findall(r'(#(?:[^#\s]+(?:\s*?)))', tag_text)
    print hash_tags
```